# Bar Plot with position="dodge", reordered and grouped

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the following data as a dodged bar plot:

```
structure(list(word = c("evil", "intelligence", "medical", "revolution", 
"change", "dominate", "deplorable", "broken", "fight", "government", 
"agreement", "real", "intelligence", "medical", "system", "mainstay", 
"expert", "intelligent", "excellence", "guide"), sentiment = c("fear", 
"fear", "fear", "fear", "fear", "fear", "fear", "fear", "fear", 
"fear", "trust", "trust", "trust", "trust", "trust", "trust", 
"trust", "trust", "trust", "trust"), n = c(304L, 257L, 159L, 
152L, 127L, 118L, 96L, 92L, 81L, 79L, 300L, 297L, 257L, 159L, 
131L, 92L, 83L, 78L, 75L, 74L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), vars = "sentiment", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:9, 10:19), group_sizes = c(10L, 10L), biggest_group_size = 10L, labels = structure(list(
    sentiment = c("fear", "trust")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), vars = "sentiment", drop = TRUE, indices = list(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 15L, 18L), c(0L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 17L, 19L)), group_sizes = c(10L, 10L), biggest_group_size = 10L))
```

On the x axis I am looking at the words to appear and on the y axis, the count n. However I'd like to compare these top 10 words by their sentiment side by side.

I have tried this code which obviously doesn't give the desired result:

```
ggplot(x, aes(fill=sentiment, y=n, x=word)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+coord_flip()
```

What I'd like to see is the words evil & agreement together, followed by intelligence and real and so on..

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(sentiment) %>% 
  mutate(index=1:n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(index), y=n, fill=sentiment)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    geom_text(aes(y=0,label=word), hjust=0,
              position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
      coord_flip()
```

[image]

Or you can try a `facet_wrap` solution

```
d %>% 
    group_by(sentiment) %>% 
    mutate(index=1:n()) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=word, y=n,fill=sentiment)) +
    geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    coord_flip() + 
    facet_wrap(~index, scale="free_y", strip.position="right", ncol=1) + 
    theme(strip.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

In both solutions you need to add an index using e.g. `tidyverse` to define which words belong together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make `word` into a `factor` like that :

```
x$word <- factor(x$word, levels = c("evil", "agreement", "intelligence", "real","medical", "revolution", 
                                "change", "dominate", "deplorable", "broken", "fight", "government", 
                                "intelligence", "medical", "system", "mainstay", 
                                "expert", "intelligent", "excellence", "guide"),
             labels  = c("evil", "agreement", "intelligence", "real","medical", "revolution", 
                         "change", "dominate", "deplorable", "broken", "fight", "government", 
                         "intelligence", "medical", "system", "mainstay", 
                         "expert", "intelligent", "excellence", "guide"))


ggplot(x, aes(fill=sentiment, y=n, x=word)) +
       geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+coord_flip()
```